# How do i update state in my Modal Popup and also in a Stateful Widget at once in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have a Stateful Widget where i pass a method from my controller to toggle the value of a bool `isLiked`

This is the method in the controller :

```
final isLiked = false.obs;


void toggleLikedIcon() {
    isLiked.value = !isLiked.value;
  }
```

And this is how i control the state in my Stateful Widget :

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        controller.toggleLikedIcon();
                        controller.isLiked.isTrue
                            ? addedToFavoriteToast()
                            : null;
                      });
                    },
                    child: controller.isLiked.isFalse
                        ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                            size: 22, color: Color(0xff34495E))
                        : Icon(
                            Icons.favorite_outlined,
                            size: 22,
                            color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                          ),
                  ),
```

However i have a function in same Stateful widget that is responsible for my modal bottom sheet :

```
void merchantDeatails(BuildContext ctx) {
    final controller = Get.find<HomeController>();
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      elevation: 10,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: ctx,
      builder: (ctx) => FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 0.8,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(30.0)),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 11,
              ),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                  width: 40,
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Share',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Color(0xff263B4F),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.shortcut_outlined,
                          size: 25,
                          color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                   
                     StatefulBuilder(
                       builder: ((context, setState) => GestureDetector(onTap: () {
                           setState(() {
                             controller.toggleLikedIcon();
                             controller.isLiked.isTrue
                                 ? addedToFavoriteToast()
                                 : null;
                           });
                         },child: Container(
                           child: controller.isLiked.isFalse
                               ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                                   size: 22, color: Color(0xff34495E))
                               : Icon(
                                   Icons.favorite_outlined,
                                   size: 22,
                                  color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                                 ),
                         ),)),

                     )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
 ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This modal popup has an icon just like the Stateful Widget and uses same bool value in my controller `isLiked`, and i use a Stateful Builder in this modal popup function to handle the state of the icon.

However when i tap the button, it only updates the state in my Popup Modal but my Stateful Widget doesn't rebuild.

Please is it possible to update the state in my Popup modal and also rebuild my Stateful Widget instantly when this icon is tapped instead of having to refresh my application before i see the state in my Stateful Widget change?

I also thought about using callback functions but it seem that i don't use it properly or it doesn't seem to work. I need help

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this question, In my method where i have my Modal bottom popup modal i replaced `StatefulBuilder` with `GetBuilder` since i am using GetX as my state management.

This is how it now looks like :

```html
GetBuilder(
        init: HomeController(),
        builder: (context) {
          return  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        controller.toggleLikedIcon();
                        controller.isLiked.isTrue
                            ? addedToFavoriteToast()
                            : null;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: controller.isLiked.isFalse
                          ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                              size: 22, color: Color(0xff34495E))
                          : Icon(
                              Icons.favorite_outlined,
                              size: 22,
                              color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                            ),
                    ),
                  ); } ),
```

Then in my controller i added `update()` as thus:

```html
void toggleLikedIcon() {
    isLiked.value = !isLiked.value;
    update();
  }
```